# Powershell Filtering

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

So I'm writing a script that connects to Azure AD and Exchange Online to retrieve all mailboxes over 90gb of usage, the only problem is that it takes a lot of time because it runs through all mailboxes even those who don't get to 90gb, when I'm trying to use the "-Filter" argument I get an error that it's not recognized in the cmdlet.

This is my line -

```
$members = Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | %{Get-MailboxStatistics $_.distinguishedname} | Select Identity, DisplayName, @{name=”TotalItemSize”; expression={[math]::Round(($_.TotalItemSize.ToString().Split(“(“)[1].Split(” “)[0].Replace(“,”,””)/1GB),2)}}, ItemCount -Filter "TotalItemSize -gt 90"
```

Answer (score 0):

`-Filter` is not a parameter of `Select-Object`

This should fix it:

`$members = Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited -Filter "TotalItemSize -gt '90'" | %{Get-MailboxStatistics $_.distinguishedname} | Select Identity, DisplayName, @{name=”TotalItemSize”; expression={[math]::Round(($_.TotalItemSize.ToString().Split(“(“)[1].Split(” “)[0].Replace(“,”,””)/1GB),2)}}, ItemCount`

Comment: `"TotalItemSize -gt '90'"` so larger than 90 BYTES..

Comment: Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": ""TotalItemSize" is not a recognized filterable 
property.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, property `TotalItemSize` is not amongst the [Filterable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/filter-properties?view=exchange-ps#filterable-properties), so you are left with either using a ForEach-Object loop like this:

```
$threshHoldBytes = 90GB   # --> 96636764160 bytes
$largeMailBoxes  = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | ForEach-Object {
    $totalByteSize = [int64]($_.TotalItemSize.ToString() -replace '^[^\(]+\(([\d,]+\s*bytes)\)', '$1' -replace '\D')
    if ($totalByteSize -gt $threshHoldBytes) {
        $_ | Select-Object Identity DisplayName, 
                           @{Name = 'TotalItemSize (GB)'; Expression={[math]::Round($totalByteSize / 1Gb, 2)}}, 
                           ItemCount
    }
}

# display on screen
$largeMailBoxes | Format-Table -AutoSize  # or use Out-GridView if it doesn't fit the console width

# export to Csv
$largeMailBoxes | Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\OverSizedMailboxes.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

OR use a `Where-Object` clause (this means you have to do the math twice though..)

```
$threshHoldBytes = 90GB   # --> 96636764160 bytes
$largeMailBoxes  = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | 
                   Where-Object { [int64]($_.TotalItemSize.ToString() -replace '^[^\(]+\(([\d,]+\s*bytes)\)', '$1' -replace '\D') -gt $threshHoldBytes } |
                   Select-Object Identity DisplayName, 
                                 @{Name = 'TotalItemSize (GB)'; Expression={[math]::Round([int64]($_.TotalItemSize.ToString() -replace '^[^\(]+\(([\d,]+\s*bytes)\)', '$1' -replace '\D') / 1Gb, 2)}}, 
                                 ItemCount

# display on screen
$largeMailBoxes | Format-Table -AutoSize  # or use Out-GridView if it doesn't fit the console width

# export to Csv
$largeMailBoxes | Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\OverSizedMailboxes.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

You could also create a small helper function that does the math, so the code gets easier on the eyes:

```
function Get-ItemSizeInGB ([string]$totalSize) {
    # you can also use this function for property TotalDeletedItemSize
    $byteSize = [int64]($totalSize -replace '^[^\(]+\(([\d,]+\s*bytes)\)', '$1' -replace '\D')
    # return the size in Gb, rounded to two decimals
    [math]::Round($byteSize / 1Gb, 2)
}
```

Now you can do

```
$threshHoldGB   = 90  # this time, we have a threshold in Gb
$largeMailBoxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | 
                  Where-Object { (Get-ItemSizeInGB $_.TotalItemSize.ToString()) -gt $threshHoldGB } |
                  Select-Object Identity DisplayName, 
                                @{Name = 'TotalItemSize (GB)'; Expression={(Get-ItemSizeInGB $_.TotalItemSize.ToString())}}, 
                                ItemCount

# display on screen
$largeMailBoxes | Format-Table -AutoSize  # or use Out-GridView if it doesn't fit the console width

# export to Csv
$largeMailBoxes | Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\OverSizedMailboxes.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Regex details:

```
^              Assert position at the beginning of the string
[^\(]          Match any character that is NOT a “(”
   +           Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\(             Match the character “(” literally
(              Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [\d,]       Match a single character present in the list below
               A “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script)
               The literal character “,”
      +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \s          Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line)
      *        Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   bytes       Match the character string “bytes” literally (case sensitive)
)             
\)             Match the character “)” literally

The `-replace '\D'` removes all non-numeric characters
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$members = Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | %{Get-MailboxStatistics $_.distinguishedname} | Select Identity, DisplayName, @{name=”TotalItemSize”; expression={[math]::Round(($_.TotalItemSize.ToString().Split(“(“)[1].Split(” “)[0].Replace(“,”,””)/1GB),2)}}, ItemCount  | ?{$_.TotalItemSize -gt 90}
```